# jQuery: delegating clicks to elements that contain other elements

Tags: jquery

So i get the gist of $.delegate and I know why it's doing what it's doing, but I'm wondering if there is a work around.

I have link elements that contain spans like so:

```
<a href='#'>
    <span>Person Name</span>
    <span>Person Info</span>
</a>
```

I use the following code in jQuery for event delegation:

```
containerElement.delegate('click','a',function(){...});
```

The trouble is that this only triggers when I click on white space not occupied by a span.  I know it does this because delegate simply compares the event target to 'a' to check if it should fire the delegate, however I want to include the spans as well, pretty much anything inside the `<a>...</a>`

what do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment I think you're looking for the following:

```
target.is('a, a > *');
```

.. or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

you have written it the other way around. the first argument is the selector and the second one is the event name

$('body').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
                alert('hi');
            });

Comment: Your incorrectness not withstanding, that doesn't even begin to answer my question.

Comment: @Master it kind of does, have you tested it? I just did and it triggers for me just fine even if I'm clicking in a span. Perhaps you need to word your question better if that's not what you're looking for?

Comment: @Master, I tested it as well and when you put the arguments in the correct order it works fine. Clicking the text within the span tags triggers the event.

Comment: ah, the function is overwritten by my validation plugin... which uses the syntax I described.  I wonder how to fix that... that said it uses $.is() to determine if the event target matches the selector.  so I guess a better question would be what do I pass to $.is() to make it match the 'a' or anything inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jquery live?

http://api.jquery.com/live/

It's built in delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Like, vinhboy suggests, I'd use

```
$("a").live("click", myFunction);

function myFunction()
{
   alert("Hello");
}
```

In fact, give your a tags a class such as "myLink" and then perform on that

```
$("a.myLink").live("click", myFunction);

function myFunction()
{
   alert("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Read: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ -- Delegate is a shortcut to `each` > `live`. Not the other way around.